# Can't force Apache Karaf to load a new version of the bundle (version w/o "-SNAPSHOT")

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-karaf

I've tried to update bundle in Karaf without changing its version. Version doesn't contain "-SNAPSHOT".
Is there a way to do it?

I've installed bundle to Apache Karaf through the mvn link
The code inside this bundle was changed without changing its (bundle's) version (according to some inner reasons).
Then I removed this bundle from Karaf, and from Nexus. 
Next step was deploying new bundle to Nexus.

When I finally tried to install the "new" bundle, I saw there were no changes in it.

It looks like there is some cache inside Karaf where he stores bundles, that was already installed.

Adding flags like -c or -cc doesn't help.

Comment: You sure the version in the local .m2 repo was updated?  Perhaps it updates from the local repo, and unless you "force update", it won't update from the remote repo, because there's already that version locally.  Just a guess

Comment: djb, thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to look up to it